# SQL Server 2008 Querying Soap XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, soap

I have been trying to process this SOAP XML return using T-SQL but all I get is NULL or nothing at all. I have tried different ways and pasted them all below.

```
Declare @xmlMsg xml;

Set @xmlMsg = 
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendWarrantyEmailResponse xmlns="http://Web.Services.Warranty/">
      <SendWarrantyEmailResult xmlns="http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult">
        <WarrantyNumber>120405000000015</WarrantyNumber>
        <Result>Cannot Send Email to anonymous account!</Result>
        <HasError>true</HasError>
        <MsgUtcTime>2012-06-07T01:11:36.8665126Z</MsgUtcTime>
      </SendWarrantyEmailResult>
    </SendWarrantyEmailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

declare @table table (data xml);
insert into @table values (@xmlMsg);

select data from @table;

WITH xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap], 'http://Web.Services.Warranty' as SendWarrantyEmailResponse, 'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as SendWarrantyEmailResult)
SELECT Data.value('(/soap:Envelope[1]/soap:Body[1]/SendWarrantyEmailResponse[1]/SendWarrantyEmailResult[1]/WarrantyNumber[1])[1]','VARCHAR(500)') AS WarrantyNumber
FROM @Table ;

;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],'http://Web.Services.Warranty' as SendWarrantyEmailResponse,'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as SendWarrantyEmailResult)
--select @xmlMsg.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult/WarrantyNumber)[0]', 'nvarchar(max)')
--select T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') from @xmlMsg.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult') as T(N)
select @xmlMsg.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult/HasError)[1]','bit') as test

;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],'http://Web.Services.Warranty' as [SendWarrantyEmailResponse],'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as [SendWarrantyEmailResult])
SELECT
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('WarrantyNumber[1]','varchar(max)') AS WarrantyNumber,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('Result[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('HasError[1]','bit') AS HasError,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('MsgUtcTime[1]','datetime') AS MsgUtcTime
FROM @xmlMsg.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult') SendWarrantyEmailResults(SendWarrantyEmailResult)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I had a moment to rethink, and I came up with the answer, so i'm sure someone out there will be looking for this.

Take a close look at the abbreviation of the namespace that's the magic that makes it all work. Hope this helps someone out there

```
Declare @xmlMsg xml;

Set @xmlMsg = 
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendWarrantyEmailResponse xmlns="http://Web.Services.Warranty/">
      <SendWarrantyEmailResult xmlns="http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult">
        <WarrantyNumber>120405000000015</WarrantyNumber>
        <Result>Cannot Send Email to anonymous account!</Result>
        <HasError>true</HasError>
        <MsgUtcTime>2012-06-07T01:11:36.8665126Z</MsgUtcTime>
      </SendWarrantyEmailResult>
    </SendWarrantyEmailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

declare @table table (data xml);
insert into @table values (@xmlMsg);

select data from @table;

WITH xmlnamespaces (
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap], 
'http://Web.Services.Warranty/' as Resp, 
'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as Res)
SELECT Data.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Resp:SendWarrantyEmailResponse/Res:SendWarrantyEmailResult/Res:WarrantyNumber)[1]','VARCHAR(500)') AS WarrantyNumber
FROM @Table ;

;with xmlnamespaces(
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],
'http://Web.Services.Warranty/' as Resp,
'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as Res)
select @xmlMsg.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Resp:SendWarrantyEmailResponse/Res:SendWarrantyEmailResult/Res:WarrantyNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
--select T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') from @xmlMsg.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult:SendWarrantyEmailResult') as T(N)
--select @xmlMsg.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendWarrantyEmailResponse/SendWarrantyEmailResult/SendWarrantyEmailResult:HasError)[1]','bit') as test

;with xmlnamespaces(
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],
'http://Web.Services.Warranty/' as Resp,
'http://Web.Services.SendWarrantyResult' as Res)
SELECT
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('Res:WarrantyNumber[1]','varchar(max)') AS WarrantyNumber,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('Res:Result[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('Res:HasError[1]','bit') AS HasError,
 SendWarrantyEmailResult.value('Res:MsgUtcTime[1]','datetime') AS MsgUtcTime
FROM @xmlMsg.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Resp:SendWarrantyEmailResponse/Res:SendWarrantyEmailResult') SendWarrantyEmailResults(SendWarrantyEmailResult)
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your answers. It helped me solve an issue that we were having, and it makes this site better as a whole when people contribute even when they weren't able to receive help.